# Clarification on the Interpretation of Gradient Vectors

Tags: vector-analysis, machine-learning, gradient-descent

This is a quick question! I keep seeing gradient vectors explained as such:

> "If you imagine standing at a point $(x_0,y_0...)$ in the input space
> $f$, the vector $\triangledown f$$(x_0,y_0...)$ tells you which
> direction you should travel to increase the value of $f$ most rapidly"

[(one example of where I got this explanation of a gradient
vector)](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/partial-derivative-and-gradient-articles/a/the-gradient).

Now the big problem I have with this is, it feels like it does not really make sense in the context of what the math is doing (unless I am misunderstanding gradient vectors). As in, the gradient vector is a combination of all the individual effects ("work" could be a way to say it) each variable in the `multivariable-function` contributes towards the rate-of-change of the output for that function. So, this means that the gradient vector is not representing "the direction you should travel to increase the output of $f$$(x_0,y_0...)$ most rapidly" because there is no "choice", the gradient vector just models (is a representation of) the intrinsic property of how the output of a function will change, with or without specific input.

**[BAD ANALOGY AHEAD]:** It would be like someone asking me where they need to go to get to a coffee shop, and I point in a direction of the store. The direction I point is determined by the location of the store and is not different depending on where the person I am talking to is standing.

One other explanation of the gradient vector that often comes as a result of the previous explanation is:

> "The gradient vector encapsulates the combined effects of all the partial derivatives, representing the direction of steepest ascent."

The "representing the direction of steepest ascent", implies that the gradient vector has other possible ascents that are "less steep", but this is not true, right?! Since the gradient vector as a whole is just the modeling of the rate-of-change of the output of an input that is intrinsic to a function, there is no other "option" for ascending, except the one option we have which is modeled by the gradient vector.

**[ANOTHER BAD ANALOGY AHEAD]:** It's like saying, "our function is $f(x) = 2x$ so $f'(x) = 2$ gives us our direction of steepest ascent!" But that isn't true, `2` is the ONLY ascent, its not like there are other "less steep" ascents that are possible for this function.

I think a better (ROUGH) explanation of the gradient vector would be something like:

> The gradient vector combines all the variable's individual contributions to rate-of-change in a multivariable function to model the direction of the rate-of-change for an output of the function.

That is super rough, but I think it gets the jist. Am I missing something? Or are these explanations leading me astray?

Comment: If I'm standing at a point I can go any direction I want. The gradient is a sign-post telling me which way is up. Just think about an asymmetric hill to get an idea of the sort of surface you can be moving along.  You'll be using the gradient to find minima in a way that's analogous with Euler's Method. Basically you travel as fast as you can to the bottom and that's exactly when the gradient is zero. It will only be a local minima but that's often good enough, especially if the function is convex as that will ensure a global minima. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard motivation for this is in terms of directional derivatives.

Define the derivative of a real-valued function $f$ (say on $\mathbb{R}^n$) in the direction of a vector $u$ as

$$\nabla_u f = u \cdot \nabla f.$$

It’s easy to see that this quantity is maximized among vectors of unit norm by $v = \nabla f/|\nabla f|$, since this vector is parallel to $\nabla f$ at each point.  This yields

$$ \nabla_v f = |\nabla f|, $$

illustrating why the gradient is called the direction of maximal increase.

EDIT:  Your misunderstanding seems to come from the fact that you think partial derivatives cannot be represented as directional derivatives.  This is false.  Let $e_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector, then

$$ \nabla_{e_i}f = e_i\cdot \nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}. $$

Moreover, $\nabla f = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} e_i$, so the gradient really is a linear combination of basis vectors.

Comment: I left a big comment on the answer that @user317176 gave! It is long but has a TLDR. You are welcome to read it and change your answer! Not that yours is wrong, but change it in a way to help me understand.

Comment: There are many vectors at each point. The gradient is one of them, and represents steepest ascent as explained in my answer.  You seem to think this is redundant. Can you explain why?

Comment: Sure! If I understand you correctly, you're saying that there are many vectors represented by the partial derivatives, and the gradient vector is one that points in the steepest ascent direction. This makes sense to me, and I understand that! However, it seems to me that comparing the gradient vector to its individual components is akin to comparing a set of directions to a single step in those directions. Ill show what I mean with another bad coffee shop analogy in the next comment.

Comment: So, if someone provides the directions (gradient vector) to a coffee shop from any position you are currently at, like, "1.) Walk West for determined # of units. 2.) Walk North for determined # of units".  It is not sensible to say that "Walking North alone won't get you to the coffee shop" because the directions are meant to be followed together, just like the partial derivatives work together to create the gradient vector. It does not make sense to compare the sum of its parts with one of the parts alone.

Comment: So, its not about the other vectors being redundant (they most certainly matter!). It is more about how the gradient vector is the combination of the partial derivatives, and so comparing them individually makes little sense. An individual partial derivative cannot be called "one of the directions your functions output changes that it less steep" because an individual partial derivative on its own is not (trying to) modeling the output of the function!

Comment: I see your misunderstanding.  See my edit for details.

Comment: Perfect edit! That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

To use the analogy of the coffee shop.  Suppose the coffee shop is two blocks to the south, and three blocks to the west.

We can then model the function $f(x,y)$ as your your current distance from the front door.

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ gives the change in distance as we travel in the east-west direction.

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$ gives the change in distance as we travel in the north-south direction.

$(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial f}{\partial y})$ points directly away from the store (the direction maximizes the change in distance).

How I was introduced to the gradient… given the surface $F(x,y,z) = k$.

$\nabla F$ points perpendicular to the surface at any point on the surface.

Comment: First off, I want to say I really like your answer, and it's use of the analogy! That being said, In the next few comments I sort of worked through what I am trying to get at. While I invite you to read the next few comments, I wont blame you if you go "TLDR" haha. But I can sort of boil the TLDR into:

Comment: [TLDR] So if we say that a gradient vector for a one-dimensional function is the slope of the tangent line. Then why in the case of multivariable function, we say that the gradient vector represents the direction and magnitude of the steepest ascent. Instead of something like, "it represents the combination of all the slopes of the tangent lines (with respect to each individual variable) in a vector with a magnitude and direction".

Comment: [TLDR] Rapid fire questions: Is it conventions or emphasis? If the emphasis on "steepest ascent", is to highlight the specific direction in which the function increases most rapidly, then why don't we call it just "direction of ascent  in which the function increases". Why does there have to be a "most rapidly"? Why for a one-dimensional function, we don't say, that the one-dimensional gradient represents "the steepest ascent" since technically there are multiple directions in an output?

Comment: [PART 1 OF LONG STORY, NOT SHORT] I just thought about it some more, and I want you to check my thinking! I think I got it now! So let's say you were given a function $f(x) = x^2$, and you wanted to know what the rate-of-change of the output at a specific point $x = 2$ was (and looked like). Well that is easy! Plugging the $x = 2$ into the derivative of the original function, $f'(x) = 2x$, would give you the rate-of-change because the derivative with respect to gives you the slope of the tangent line at that specific point $x = 2$,

Comment: [PART 2]  which is the rate-of-change for the output of the original function (again, at $x = 2$). Little did I know, but I was technically using gradient vectors here too, where the slope of the tangent line can be thought of as the gradient vector! It's just that they had only one dimension and so also had an inherent respect to $x$. So it would be literal extra work using the gradient vector on single variable functions like this, so that is why we don't and do it a "shorter" way.

Comment: [PART 3] But now let's say you want to know what the rate-of-change in output of an original function that is multi-variable, $f(x,y) = 2x^2 + xy + y$, for a point $(4,5)$ in the input space. Well this is where it gets tricky, to find the actual rate-of-change vector that gives the direction (and magnitude) that the original function's output moves in, we would need to input an infinitely small $x$ and an infinitely small $y$.

Comment: [PART 4] With just the original function and the point in the input space $(4,5)$, we would be required to actually plug in an infinitely small $x$ and $y$. But THIS IS obviously IMPOSSIBLE to do practically! So you cannot make the net rate-of-change vector for that point with only the original function $f(x,y)$ and the point $(4,5)$. We got around this impossibility before by making a gradient vector before (of one dimension)! And I didn't even realize it. So we no can use our saving grace again, the gradient vector.

Comment: [PART 5] If we have the same setup, with just the original function $f(x,y)$ and the point $(4,5)$, BUT we now also have a calculated gradient vector, ∇$f(x,y) = [4x + y, x + 1]$. Now when we ask that same question, "How do we get a vector that shows how the rate-of-change of the output looks?"

Comment: [FINAL PART] We can plug $(4,5)$ into the gradient vector to create a new set of "points" (vector) which accurately models what the rate-of-change of the output looks like as a vector, where $(4,5)$ going to $(\frac{1}{\infty} , \frac{1}{\infty})$. This vector (made from the gradient vector) in a way models the combination of all of the slopes of the tangent lines at a specific point, with respect to each of the variables individually.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is, can you give me an input for a gradient vector that gives a vector output that is NOT the steepest ascent? See how it's confusing because I know that you cant because there's only one possible vector you can get as an output for each individual input of points in our entire input space, even if it is size infinity. So why are we saying "steepest" when there is only one. Would I say, "this is my "green-est" car", if I only owned one car. No! I would say this is my green car. Just like, "this is my gradient vector that models ascent".